# Appharbor JustOneDb MVC sample link broken

Tags: model-view-controller, appharbor

Does anyone have or know where the appharbor JustOneDb MVC sample is?
the link they give appears to be broke.

What they wrote:
A sample MVC application can be found here:

https://github.com/appharbor/JustOneDB-Sample-MVC-Application

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for alerting us to this error, I have updated the documentation. The sample app can be found here: https://github.com/appharbor/PostgreSQL-Sample-MVC-Application